# How can I query List of Dict using filterExpressions for DynamoDB

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, boto3, filterexpression

I am currently working on a project that involves using Amazon DynamoDB as the database for storing and retrieving data. In one of my DynamoDB tables, I have a field that is a List of Dict (Dictionary) objects. Each element in the list is a dictionary with key-value pairs, and I need to perform queries on this list based on specific criteria using filter expressions.

Here's an example structure of the DynamoDB item:

```
{
  "UserId": "12345",
  "DataList": [
    {"Key": "A", "Value": "Value1"},
    {"Key": "B", "Value": "Value2"},
    {"Key": "C", "Value": "Value3"}
  ]
}
```

Now, I want to query items in the DynamoDB table where the DataList contains a dictionary with a specific key-value pair, e.g., "Key": "B" and "Value": "Value2". I have tried using filter expressions, but I'm struggling to come up with the correct expression to achieve this.

Could someone please provide guidance on how to construct a filter expression that allows me to query a List of Dict in DynamoDB based on specific criteria? Any examples or code snippets would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use [`contains()`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.html#Expressions.OperatorsAndFunctions.Syntax) function. In that function, you need to pass the entire map into it as a parameter to search on, you cannot just search on an individual string within the map. Here is an example using the CLI:

```
aws dynamodb scan \
--table-name myTable \
--filter-expression 'contains(#c, :c)' \
--expression-attribute-names '{"#c": "DataList"}' \
--expression-attribute-values '{":c":{"M":{"Key": {"S": "A"},"Value": {"S": "Value1"}}}}'
```